# Big O Notation O(n^2) what does it mean?

Tags: data-structures, big-o, selection-sort

For example, it says that in 1 sec 3000 number are sorted with selection sort. How can we predict how many numbers are gonna be sorted in 10 sec ?

I checked that selection sort needs O(n^2) but I dont understand how I am gonna calculate how many numbers are gonna be sorted in 10 sec.

Comment: Big O notation has nothing to do with specific time measurments.  Some more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

Comment: *"I dont understand how I am gonna calculate how many numbers are gonna be sorted in 10 sec"*: me neither. If someone tells you that there is a formula to calculate it, they show that have not understood what big O is about. It is a misunderstanding that many have, including teachers.

Comment: @wohlstad I think big-oh notation is perfectly usable as a ***relative*** factor in time calculations. Please check my answer and tell me if I am wrong.  (Please prove me wrong if you can.)

Comment: @trincot I think big-oh notation is perfectly usable as a ***relative*** factor in time calculations. Please check my answer and tell me if I am wrong.  (Please prove me wrong if you can.)

Comment: It seems you make the common mistake too, @MikeNakis. Big O tells us something about asymptotic behavjour, not about how one result allows to predict another.

Answer (score 4):

We cannot use big O to reliably extrapolate actual running times or input sizes (whichever is the unknown).

Imagine the same code running on two machines A and B, different parsers, compilers, hardware, operating system, array implementation, ...etc.

Let's say they both can parse and run the following code:

```
procedure sort(reference A)
    declare i, j, x
    i ← 1
    n ← length(A)
    while i < n
        x ← A[i]
        j ← i - 1
        while j >= 0 and A[j] > x
            A[j+1] ← A[j]
            j ← j - 1
        end while
        A[j+1] ← x[3]
        i ← i + 1
    end while
end procedure
```

Now system A spends 0.40 seconds on the initialisation part before the loop starts, independent on what A is, because on that configuration the initiation of the function's execution context including the allocation of the variables is a very, very expensive operation. It also needs to spend 0.40 seconds on the de-allocation of the declared variables and the call stack frame when it arrives at the end of the procedure, again because on that configuration the memory management is very expensive. Furthermore, the `length` function is costly as well, and takes 0.19 seconds. That's a total overhead of 0.99 seconds

On system B this memory allocation and de-allocation is cheap and takes 1 microsecond. Also the `length` function is fast and needs 1 microsecond. That's a total overhead that is 2 microseconds.

System A is however much faster on the rest of the statements in comparison with system B.

Both implementations happen to need 1 second to sort an array A having 3000 values.

If we now take the reasoning that we could predict the array size that can be sorted in 10 seconds based on the results for 1 second, we would say:

> = 3000, and the duration is 1 second which corresponds to ² = 9 000 000 operations. So if 9 000 000 operations corresponds to 1 second, then 90 000 000 operations correspond to 10 seconds, and  = √(²) ~= 9 487 (the size of the array that can be sorted in 10 seconds).

However, if we follow the same reasoning, we can look at the time needed for completing the outer loop only (without the initialisation overhead), which **also** is O(²) and thus the same reasoning can be followed:

> = 3000, and the duration in system A is 0.01 second which corresponds to ² = 9 000 000 operations. So if 9 000 000 operations can be executed in 0.01 second then in 10 - 0.99 seconds (overhead is subtracted) we can execute 9.01 / 0.01 operations, i.e  ² = 8 109 000 000 operations, and now  = √(²) ~= 90 040.

The problem is that using the same reasoning on big O, the predicted outcomes differ by a factor of about 10!

We may be tempted to think that this is now only a "problem" of constant overhead, but similar things can be said about operations in the outer loop. For instance it might be that `x ← A[i]` has a relatively high cost for some reason on some system. These are factors that are not revealed in the big O notation, which only retains the most significant factor, omitting linear and constant factors that play a role.

The actual running time for an actual input size is dependent on a more complex function that is likely close to polynomial, like ² +  + . These coefficients , and  would be needed to make a more reasonable prediction possible. There might even be function components that are non-polynomial, like ² +  +  + √... This may seem unlikely, but systems on which the code runs may do all kinds of optimisations while code runs which may have such or similar effect on actual running time.

The conclusion is that this type of reasoning gives no guarantee that the prediction is anywhere near the reality -- without more information about the actual code, system on which it runs,... etc, it is nothing more than a guess. Big O is a measure for **asymptotic** behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, big-oh notation has nothing to do with specific time measurements; however, the question still makes sense, because the big-oh notation is perfectly usable as a ***relative*** factor in time calculations.

Big-oh notation gives us an indication of how the number of elementary operations performed by an algorithm varies as the number of items to process varies.

Simple algorithms perform a fixed number of operations per item, but in more complicated algorithms the number of operations that need to be performed per item varies as the number of items varies. Sorting algorithms are a typical example of such complicated algorithms.

The great thing about big-oh notation is that it belongs to the realm of science, rather than technology, because it is completely independent of your hardware, and of the speed at which your hardware is capable of performing a single operation.

However, the question tells us exactly how much time it took for some hypothetical hardware to process a certain number of items, so we have an idea of how much time that hardware takes to perform a single operation, so we can reason based on this.

If 3000 numbers are sorted in 1 second, and the algorithm operates with `O( N ^ 2 )`, this means that the algorithm performed 3000 ^ 2 = 9,000,000 operations within that second.

If given 10 seconds to work, the algorithm will perform ten times that many operations within that time, which is 90,000,000 operations.

Since the algorithm works in `O( N ^ 2 )` time, this means that after 90,000,000 operations it will have sorted `Sqrt( 90,000,000 )` = 9,486 numbers.

To verify: 9,000,000 operations within a second means 1.11e-7 seconds per operation. Since the algorithm works at `O( N ^ 2 )`, this means that to process 9,486 numbers it will require 9,486 ^ 2 operations, which is roughly equal to 90,000,000 operations. At 1.11e-7 seconds per operation, 90,000,000 operations will be done in roughly 10 seconds, so we are arriving at the same result via a different avenue.

If you are seriously pursuing computer science or programming I would recommend reading up on big-oh notation, because it is a) very important and b) a very big subject which cannot be covered in stackoverflow questions and answers.

Comment: I would also recommend that in the future you refrain from using the word "gonna"; not only it does ***not*** sound as cool as you think, but also, you are not addressing your buddies here, you are addressing people that you do not know.

Comment: I agree big-O can give you some kind of general direction when comparing algorithms execution time. And it's also very important in general for people wo want to get deep into computer science or programming. But I believe your answer is a bit missleading. In big-O notation we ignore constants.
Therefore in your example your estimation of 9486 numbers could actually be off by a factor (e.g. 94860 if the "hidden" constant is 10). In practical applications this might be a huge difference. Am I wrong ? (BTW - I didn't downvote).

Comment: The second paragraph is wrong. Big O only gives an indication about *asymptotic* behaviour, but cannot say anything about specific example of time-size correspondance. A O(n²) may have for instance have a running time that is close to 100 + 5n + n² µs or to 5000 - 3n + n² µs. Both are O(n²).

Comment: @MikeNakis hi, thank you for the response. I just wanted to say that I am sorry if I offended you, but English is not my mother language and I am really nervous about my exam so it was a quick question. I am new here.

Comment: @trincot you are saying that the second paragraph is wrong because big-oh "cannot say anything about specific example of time-size correspondance." However, the second paragraph does not say such a thing. It only speaks of "operations". Interestingly enough, even though I had not looked up the term in Wikipedia when writing my answer, I just looked at it now and it says pretty much the same thing, even using very similar terminology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: @trincot as for your second comment, your examples of various forms of n² +/- some fudge are all covered by the fact that we are discussing an ***approximation*** here.  In my answer I wrote "we have an idea of how much time that hardware takes to perform a single operation, so we can reason based on this", implying that everything which follows is approximations, and this is in accordance with the word "predict" used in the question, as opposed to "calculate", which would have implied accuracy.

Comment: @wohlstad the question is asking for a prediction, which implies an approximation, so the constant factor can be regarded as nothing but a simple, fixed time penalty per operation, which is directly calculatable from the actual measured time of 1 second and the number of operations performed. Of course, if the algorithm turned out to have a 0.9 second warm-up time then all bets would be off, but the question seems to disregard that possibility for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I have posted an answer where this factor 10 problem is illustrated with an extreme example. I really find it disturbing that this stuff is asked in exam questions.

Comment: @MikeNakis I now see that you have a point about the constant coefficient of n² being immeterial for relative comparisson. The estimation is probably not as off as I originally thought.

Comment: @trincot all you wrote in your answer is correct. But if `n` is big enough the estimation above has some meaning IMHO. Not sure though about this specific case because 1 second can contain relatively a lot of initialization time, or have effect from the other factors in the time function. Still I believe the answer is useful.

Comment: @wohlstad, the problem with that is that *"big enough"* is not defined. The definition of big O is that there is an ₀ above which a bound holds applying coefficient  (using naming as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)). We have not been given ₀ nor , so any guessing is making assumptions about information that was not given.

Comment: Notice however that the exam question did not mention *O(n^2)*; this was OP's own observation. The exam question only said we have a selection sort implementation. We know a bit more about an unknown selection sort implementation than we know about a hypothetical *O(n^2)* algorithm. So even if it is dangerous to make the extrapolation argument as in this post, I believe the original exam question is not completely misleading as you can make *some* estimation based on the actual (not asymptotic) running time function of a typical selection sort implementation.

Comment: @trincot theoretically you are 100% correct. But that doesn't mean the asnwer above is not useful. Take this variation: a common O(n^2) algorithm (like sorting, where x0 is not likely to be huge) processes 10M values per hour. Can you estimate the number of values for 5 hours ? 
I think the method suggested by MikeNakis is likely to give a fair estimation. It's the best educated guess I could think of. So big-O can offer some insight about relative measures as Mike said (with some caveats).
I think both your answers explain different aspect of the problem, and therefore upvoted both.